# Stop iteration in for loop

Tags: python

Function generates 2 boards horizontal dynamically according to size.

code:

```
import string
size = 5
def init_board(size=5) -> list:
    board = [["0"] * size for _ in range(size)]
    return board


def generate_two_boards(size, board_1, board_2):
    two_boards = (zip(board_1, board_2))

    rows_list = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:size]

    for row_board_1, row_board_2 in (two_boards):
        for row in rows_list:
            current_row_board_1 = ' '.join(row_board_1)
            current_row_board_2 = ' '.join(row_board_2)
            print("{}  {:>2}   {}  {:>2} ".format(row, current_row_board_1, row, current_row_board_2))
            # stop print after size is reached

board_1 = init_board(size)
board_2 = init_board(size)

generate_two_boards(size, board_1, board_2)
```

How to **stop iteration** after size is reached , or pint only n’th line according to board size?

Desired output when `size = 5`

```
A  0 0 0 0 0   A  0 0 0 0 0 
B  0 0 0 0 0   B  0 0 0 0 0 
C  0 0 0 0 0   C  0 0 0 0 0 
D  0 0 0 0 0   D  0 0 0 0 0 
E  0 0 0 0 0   E  0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: What does your code do now which is not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to zip the row lead together:

```py
rows_list = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:size]
rows_and_two_boards = zip(rows_list, board_1, board_2)

for lead, row_board_1, row_board_2 in rows_and_two_boards:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you're making is that you're iterating on the row boards and *within that* you're iterating on the `rows_list`.

What you should do is `zip` the rows_list alonside the boards, this way you'd get e.g. `row_name, board1_row, board2_row`. And you wouldn't need to slice the rows list because `zip` stops at the shortest iterator.

Something along the lines of (untested code)

```py
def generate_two_boards(size, board_1, board_2):
    for row, row_board_1, row_board_2 in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, board_1, board_2):
        current_row_board_1 = ' '.join(row_board_1)
        current_row_board_2 = ' '.join(row_board_2)
        print("{}  {:>2}   {}  {:>2} ".format(row, current_row_board_1, row, current_row_board_2))
        # stop print after size is reached
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` after the inner loop:

```
import string
size = 5
def init_board(size=5):
    board = [["0"] * size for _ in range(size)]
    return board


def generate_two_boards(size, board_1, board_2):
    two_boards = (zip(board_1, board_2))

    rows_list = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:size]

    for row_board_1, row_board_2 in (two_boards):
        for row in rows_list:
            current_row_board_1 = ' '.join(row_board_1)
            current_row_board_2 = ' '.join(row_board_2)
            print("{}  {:>2}   {}  {:>2} ".format(row, current_row_board_1, row, current_row_board_2))
        break
        
           

board_1 = init_board(size)
board_2 = init_board(size)

generate_two_boards(size, board_1, board_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

solution is:

```
def generate_two_boards2(size, board_1, board_2):
    for row, row_board_1, row_board_2 in zip(string.ascii_uppercase[:size], board_1, board_2):
        current_row_board_1 = ' '.join(row_board_1)
        current_row_board_2 = ' '.join(row_board_2)
        print("{}  {:>2}   {}  {:>2} ".format(row, current_row_board_1, row, current_row_board_2))

board_1 = init_board(size)
board_2 = init_board(size)

generate_two_boards2(size, board_1, board_2)
```

or simply **break** in loop:

```
for row_board_1, row_board_2 in (two_boards):
    for row in rows_list:
        current_row_board_1 = ' '.join(row_board_1)
        current_row_board_2 = ' '.join(row_board_2)
        print("{}  {:>2}   {}  {:>2} ".format(row, current_row_board_1, row, current_row_board_2))
    break
```